# Unix way to send/transmit raw Ethernet frame

Tags: networking, ethernet, utilities

I want to send raw Ethernet data, kind of like netcat for Ethernet instead of TCP. What is the simplest way to do this on Unix? So far it looks like I need to write my own tool.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simple to achieve in Python, see [Github: One way of sending raw Ethernet packets in Python](https://gist.github.com/cslarsen/11339448)

```py
from socket import *
def sendeth(src, dst, eth_type, payload, interface = "eth0"):
  assert(len(src) == len(dst) == 6) # 48-bit ethernet addresses
  assert(len(eth_type) == 2) # 16-bit ethernet type
  s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
  s.bind((interface, 0))
  return s.send(src + dst + eth_type + payload)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("Sent %d-byte Ethernet packet on eth0" %
  sendeth("\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xBE\xEF",
          "\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xBE\xEF",
          "\x7A\x05",
          "hello"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a Python script much like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Does Scapy enought for you ?
It allows you to build your own packets. →
https://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/